# Powershell Random selection and count

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that picks up from an array 10 random items, list them and then writes which one was picked the most and how many times.

I have this:

```
for ($num = 1 ; $num -le 10 ; $num++){
$namelist = @(
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    "Item 5"
)
Get-Random -InputObject $NameList
}
```

As result it shows me 10 picks from the list, but everytime I need to count which one was picked the most.

Anyone can help?

Comment: `1..10 | % { Get-Random -InputObject $NameList } | group | sort Count | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2) with [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$namelist = @(
    "Item 1"
    "Item 2"
    "Item 3"
    "Item 4"
    "Item 5"
)

& {
    for ($num = 1 ; $num -le 10 ; $num++) {
        Get-Random -InputObject $NameList
    }
} | Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

This would return an *array of objects*, if you wanted to see which one was picked the most you can pipe it into `Select-Object -First 1`.

If you don't want to use `Group-Object` for some reason, you can also accomplish this using a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$map = @{}
for ($num = 1 ; $num -le 10 ; $num++) {
    $pick = Get-Random -InputObject $NameList
    $map[$pick] = 1 + $map[$pick]
}
$map.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object { $_.Value } -Descending
```

Comment: Sir, you just beat me on time. I've had a flash and did the exact same thing (excluded -Descending) and as going to delete the question or resolve it myself. But thank you for you answer! I really much appreciate it!